# Flutter inspector bugging out/freezing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Today was the first day I came across this issue with flutter widget inspector.  When you click "Select Widget Mode" then select an element, it will freeze, and this inception-like view will occur:
[image]

In addition, if you just resize this window in Visual Studio code, the Widget Inspector view goes blank:

[image]

I've almost lost an entire day of development because of this stupid bug.

I have a feeling something got updated automatically and broke things.  Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?  It was working so well then all the sudden today it decided to break.

Comment: Have you solved it anyhow? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, me too. I came to post this problem and don't know what's happening. I'm on Big Sur. Anyone know if this is happening on Catalina?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue and did some research.  There appears to be some bug reports around this.

- https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2581
- https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3024
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65480 (fixed here)

This will require a new release of DevTools.  Until this happens you can add the following to your VS Code settings.json.

```
"dart.embedDevTools": false,
```

This will open DevTools, from VS Code, in your browser.

Comment: This works great in the meantime and thanks for the issue links. Just an FYI to others that your browser will prompt you to allow it fall back to a previous version that doesn't use WebGL. You'll need to allow that or you'll run into the same issues in the browser.