# How do I fix Dart DevTools Widget Inspector that is stuck showing a circular progress indicator?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-devtools

I had a Flutter app crash while I was debugging it from the Dart DevTool "Logging" page. After this occurred, all I see when I start debugging is that the Widget Inspector shows a circular progress indicator.  I'm now testing with the Flutter default app so it's not something in my code.  I've tried restarting my computer a couple of times and the behavior hasn't changed.

An answer to a similar problem ([Flutter inspector bugging out/freezing in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514306/flutter-inspector-bugging-out-freezing-in-visual-studio-code)) suggested adding `dart.embedDevTools": false,` to my VSCode settings.json file. I tried that and still get the same behavior, just in a browser window. Aside: this seems to suggest that the problem is not in VSCode. Finally, I also tried running the app from the command line and launching the DevTools application server directly--same problem.

Any ideas of how I might fix this would be appreciated! If there are none, I guess I will have to try uninstalling and re-installing Flutter and Dart to see if that fixes the problem.

```
>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

>flutter clean
Deleting build...                                                  132ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              4.4s
Deleting .packages...                                                3ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       4ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            2ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            3ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         4ms

>flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in default_app...                      1,273ms

>flutter pub global run devtools

>flutter run -d chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally reached a point where I had time to recover if the reinstall failed so here's what I did to fix this problem:

```
cd {installdir}\flutter
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
rem • No issues found!
```

The issue was *probably* fixed at this point but I went ahead and did the following (except for the two rem steps that I only do when trying to figure out package dependency issues):

```
cd {projectsdir}\appname
flutter pub upgrade
rem flutter pub outdated
rem flutter pub deps -s list
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ..
code appname           // Open folder in VScode
<F5>
```

**At this point, DevTools Widget Inspector and Logging are working again!!**

Thanks to Suragch who posted the Git steps in an answer to [How do you uninstall Flutter completely and properly from a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760735/how-do-you-uninstall-flutter-completely-and-properly-from-a-mac).

It would be nice to add this info to the [Flutter Windows install page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) but I'm not sure how to even suggest that.

**Final Thoughts**

There could be issues where this refresh doesn't work. In that case--and in the case where one didn't install flutter as a git repository--I believe that the fix would be:

```
* delete the flutter directory where you installed flutter,
* remove the paths related to flutter from your environment variable PATH, and
* install Flutter per the install page.
```

I caution that I haven't tested this approach! If anyone encounters a problem that forces them to resort to this fix, posting an answer here would be appreciated.